# Animations between different states of a ListboxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I try to implement a ListBox where the selected item is displayed in more detail than the others. One approach is shown by Josh Smith on [his blog](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/30/customizing-the-selected-item-in-a-listbox/).

To enhance the user experience, I'd like to animate the change (i.e. the item growing larger, additional information fading in).
Using the DataTriggers Enter- or ExitActions to start Storyboard has the disadvandates, that

- I have no reusable template for the detailed view (it just exists as the end state of an animation).
- Every change to the detailed view hs to be worked in at the two animations instead of just once.

Is there another approach thats more easily maintainable?

Comment: If you're using WCF4 then maybe look at VisualStateManager . That link points to a 2007 article. See http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-visual-state-manager-overview.aspx

Comment: @Henk is right about VisualStateManager being the solution to this. (he surely meant to type WPF 4 instead of WCF 4 though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` and adjust it for your needs.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">                                
                <Border>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Compact"
                                Opacity="1"
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UnselectedDataTemplate}">
                            <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" />
                            </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Details"
                                Opacity="0"
                                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource SelectedDataTemplate}">
                            <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="0" />
                            </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState Name="Unselected">
                                <Storyboard SpeedRatio="2">
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Compact"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Compact"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Details"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Details"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard SpeedRatio="2">
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Compact"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="0"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Compact"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Details"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation To="1"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Details"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="LayoutTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>                            
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In this case I have declared the templates as resources.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UnselectedDataTemplate">
    /* your controls for unselected state */
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="SelectedDataTemplate">
    /* your controls for selected state */
</DataTemplate>
```

But I think binding datatemplated content directly to `ContentPresenter.Content` is possible too.

If **Details** are additional and not for replacement of **Compact**, simply remove all `DoubleAnimation` from `Storyboard` with `Storyboard.TargetName="Compact"`.

Hope this helps.